# WSO2 IS ASP.Net - user authentication and SAML response decoding/validation

Tags: asp.net, wso2-identity-server

We are using WSO2 IS 5.2.0 for user authentication and SSO across our applications. We have multiple web applications built on java technology.
All the apps are registered in WSO2 service provider and we are able to successfully authenticate user and able to do SSO.
User is prompted for login when he tries to access one of the apps for the first time. Once user logs in, he is able to access any application.
We are using HTTP redirect to achieve this. On the applications side we are using WSO2 java API (org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.* package) to get the authenticated user details and claims information.

Now we have one more application in .Net (ASP) which we want to integrate into our application suite which should also use the existing SSO infrastructure.

Can someone please let us know how to integrate WSO2 and .Net application for user authentication and SSO. If it is HTTP redirect, then how do we decrypt user information from the SAML Response in .Net application?

Is there any webservice interface available which we can directly call from .Net application which can provide function to get user information by passing samltokenId?

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample written using .NET in here [1] but it seems it is still undergoing development. I have asked the question in WSO2 Architecture mailing list[2] about the state of it (You can follow for more information) but still you can use it to get some understanding (Or as a full working solution maybe).

[1] https://github.com/wso2/samples-is/tree/master/dotnet-agent-saml-sso

[2] [Architecture] [IS] SAML SSO Agent for .NET